# Prepositional phrases on the internet

Tags: prepositions, dictionaries, prepositional-phrases, resources

Is there any online dictionary or database of prepositional phrases? What I would like is to enter e. g. "justification" and it would give me: "justification to somebody", "justification of something", and other possibilities (optionally with description of the meaning of each phrase).

I found this website http://www.englishpage.com/prepositions/verb_preposition.html. This is almost what I want, but it contains only few examples. I am looking for more complete list. Maybe some online dictionary might provide me with what I want, but dictionary.reference.com, which I use, does not list prepositional phrases with words (right?).

Comment: Wouldn't any dictionary do that?

Comment: I am a bit confused. *Justification* is not a verb.

Comment: That's also right, actually I wasn't sure about what to answer but I guess he got confused?

Comment: Justification is indeed noun. I mean any part of speech, not only verbs. I have updated my question.

Comment: Then you're asking the use of prepositions in ANY context? That's quite a wide thing :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking about [Government](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_%28linguistics%29) in Linguistics, right? **I think the best way** (and maybe the only one, even if I'm not aware of such lists available for English since it's not really a Case-based language) **is to study each verb on its own.**

But try searching these keywords: `government verbs`, etc.

Don't confuse this with Phrasal Verbs, which are something slightly different:
**"Government" in Linguistics means what "case" the verb governs, while a Phrasal verb is a verb which, put together with a preposition, usually, changes its meaning!**

For example:

> To find = Who? What?

The verb "to find" here governs an accusative case, which usually means Direct Object. You find **someone/something** not "prep. + someone/something".

But if you say:

> To find out = What? *(edit: there exists also "to find someone out" but even here the meaning slightly changes, although this wasn't the point.)*

Here "to find out" doesn't mean "to find something outside" (I'm making it an extreme example to make it clearer), but means *to discover*.

Comment: @Alain Pannetier: Thanks for the correction, I didn't notice it... :D

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't know about Government before. I am probably looking for something like that. I have updated my question.